# Hide package or files in intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need to test different implementations of the same classes in the spring project. I mean "entities" packages - I've created two implementations and want to run a project using different variants. How can I hide / show a package or classes for a spring project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to mark one of the packages as excluded. It used to work for me.

To exclude package: `Right click on it -> Mark Directory as -> Excluded`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the package that is scanned to find your entities with `@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.one")` where your configuration is